# How can I apply for UK family/partner visa having pre-settled status?

Tags: united-kingdom, uk-visa

I need to apply for a visa for my wife from Bangladesh.
I am living in UK from 2019 and have pre-settled status under the EU settlement scheme. I came from Italy and I have permanent resident of Italy. However my nationality is Bangladesh.

On Gov.uk there is a feature "check if you Need a Visa".
I go through the question and answer system on behalf of my wife. At one point I see this option.

[image: this is the question]

I am ok with option 3. After that the system says "You must usually apply for a family visa."

On family visa section The requirement is as below.

[image: family visa requirement]

My question : Is the option Three good for me ?? Can I sponsor my wife for family visa ?
However I know there is other requirement of family visa.

Comment: Permanent resident status in Italy does not qualify you for pre-settled status.  What is the basis of your pre-settled status?

Comment: I am a dependent child of my italian father and got pre-settle status under eu settlement scheme as a close family member.